# Shift $a + ab / c = d$ to $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The title pretty much says it. I dont geet how to shift $a+ab / c = d$ to $a$ to $a$. I have tried to multiply by $c$ but then I stumble at $ab+ab=dc$ and dont get forward.

Answer (score 1):

Once you're at $ac + ab = dc$, can you see a way to factorise by $a$ on the left hand side?

Comment: It should be dc in RHS. May be a typo.

Comment: Not realy. Then i stuck at $2a+ab+ca+cb=dc$

Comment: Can you explain how you got to that last line?

Comment: I had factorized $ac + ab = dc$ by $a$ on the left hand side?^^

Comment: Can you show me your working? I'm struggling to see how you got to where you did